# History: Line with two origins

Tags: reference-request, manifolds, differential-topology, math-history

Who was the first to explicitly mention [the line with two origins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-Hausdorff_manifold#Line_with_two_origins)? It's such a standard example, but it would be nice to know who to attribute it to, and I haven't a clue.